# Error running sonar profile

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to run Sonar code quality against my code base and getting following exception. I have successfully installed Sonar server and http://gsi-547576:9900 returns me the home page without any issues. I have not connected Sonar to any external DB and currently using default in-memory DB.

**Command using to run Sonar:**

```
mvn clean install -Psonar sonar:sonar
```

**Error Log:**

```
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: C:\nital\my-pet-projects\istore\istore-mvc2\istore-mvc2-domain\target\sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0
[INFO] [11:21:11.716] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [11:21:11.916] Load global referentials done: 200 ms
[INFO] [11:21:11.916] User cache: C:\Users\chandeln\.sonar\cache
[INFO] [11:21:11.926] Install plugins
[INFO] [11:21:11.966] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [11:21:11.976] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.576 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-04T11:21:14-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project istore-mvc2-domain: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Co
nnection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-176]) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

**settings.xml**

```
   <profile>
       <id>sonar</id>
       <properties>
          <sonar.host.url>http://gsi-547576:9900/</sonar.host.url>
       </properties>
    </profile>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.istore</groupId>
    <artifactId>istore-mvc2-domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://gsi-547576/svn/istore/istore-mvc2-domain/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://gsi-547576/svn/istore/istore-mvc2-domain/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>https://gsi-547576/svn/istore/istore-mvc2-domain/trunk</url>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Releasing a project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://gsi-547576/svn/istore/istore-mvc2-domain/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- For deploying the artifacts to Nexus -->    
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>my-nexus-server</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://gsi-547576:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>my-nexus-server</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://gsi-547576:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log indicates that you have a problem of connection with the DB, which looks logical as it appears you are not using a supported DB http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-SupportedPlatforms

Have you tried to open SonarQube after intall and before running an analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

After modifying m2 settings.xml it worked :) My updated settings.xml file

**m2/settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>http://gsi-547576:9900</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:h2:tcp://gsi-547576:9092/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```